# Why am I facing issue with junit 5 assertThrows for asserting TimedOutException despite passing expected parameters?

Tags: java, selenium, junit5, assert, timeoutexception

I'm trying to assert the TimedOutException using junit 5 assertThrows while clicking a button on page but I'm getting error, may I know the reason?[image]

```
Assert.assertThrows(TimedOutException.class, ()->{homePage.clickQuote();});
```

clickQuote() method either takes user to next page or throws TimedOutException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably imported and used the wrong class (from JUnit 4 instead of JUnit 5)

In JUnit 5 please use only `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions` instead of `org.junit.Assert`.

As you mentioned in a comment that you imported `org.unit.Assert`: This is the utility with the static assertions from JUnit 4, not JUnit 5. It provides a method `assertThrows`, but with different parameters, and is not upwards compatible with JUnit 5. Usually you expect exceptions in JUnit 4 with the help of annotations.

You can find details on the method parameters in the [API docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows-java.lang.Class-org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable-) of JUnit 5.

Comment: I imported 
import org.junit.Assert; 
The snapshot shows what the method expects and the parameter I've passed
Junit version is 5.7.1

Comment: There is no `org.junit.Assert` in JUnit 5. That is JUnit 4, but there you usually work differently (with annotations) to expect an exception. `Assert.assertThrows` of JUnit 4 expects the second parameter to be a `Runnable`.

Comment: I updated my answer so it suits your situation better.